# There is an integration problem of paypal api with laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating the paypal gateway with Laravel. There is a problem when I click "connect with paypal" button

The app sent to paypal link and the error shows

> invalid client_id, return uri

Don't know whether its a code problem or the account setting problem in paypal.

I have changed the return url in paypal account several times but no use.

This is my config file:

```
return array(

    'sandbox_client_id' => 'client_id_here',
    'sandbox_secret' => 'secret_here',

    'live_client_id' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'live_secret' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_SECRET'),

    'paypal_invoice_link'=>'https://www.paypal.com/invoice/payerView/details/',


    /**
     * SDK configuration settings
     */
    'settings' => array(
        /** 
         * Payment Mode
         *
         * Available options are 'sandbox' or 'live'
         */
        'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'live'),
        // Specify the max connection attempt (3000 = 3 seconds)
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 3000,
        // Specify whether or not we want to store logs
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        // Specigy the location for our paypal logs
        'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
        /** 
         * Log Level
         *
         * Available options: 'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARN' or 'ERROR'
         * 
         * Logging is most verbose in the DEBUG level and decreases 
         * as you proceed towards ERROR. WARN or ERROR would be a 
         * recommended option for live environments.
         * 
         */
```

Comment: Are these client secrets actual production secrets? In that case you may want to revoke them asap, because you have just published them to everyone

Comment: As Daniel mentioned you should revoke the access mentioned above immediately and check with a new ones if you still get the same error because invalid client_id  means the 'live_client_id' is incorrect

Comment: yes these credentials are altered and not originals ,I entered here just for asking the question